# How to retrieve an Entity Object just with @Id (Proxy object), check if it exists and assign it to a @ManyToOne association

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, proxy, entity, many-to-one

I have an entity **Product** which have many fields and associations (around 60).
And a table **ProductView** which has a *@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)* association with **Product**.

Is there a optimal way to retrieve Product object and assign it to ProductView ?

1. If its used JPA findById(productId) or JPQL/EntityManager selects-> It will retrieve all products fields and associations

   > Product product = productRepository.findById(productId);
   > ProductView productView = new ProductView(product);
   > save(productView);
2. If its used JPA getOne -> It solves the problem but the Proxy can throw error if Product does not exists. And this error can not be handled because it happens at runtime.

   > Product product = productRepository.getOne(productId);
   > ProductView productView = new ProductView(product);
   > save(productView);
3. If a DTO is used or Interface which refers to the same Product Table -> We will get just an object with Id field, but a lot more processes will need to be added (Which I am not familiar with)
4. Delete foreign keys from ProductView table (@ManyToOne -> @Column) and simple assign productIds. But in this way, there will be no logic connection between tables.

[ProductView DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npV7h.png)

How usually developers avoid this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what the problem is. Just use `getOne` approach and at the end of your method, use `flush` which will throw the constraint violation exception that you can handle. This is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, this is a great idea, thanks. Thus, it still did not solve my issue. The thing is when getOne method is called, spring boot creates a select statement (even if it's proxy). So from performance point of view, it's still not good enough.

Comment: I solved it by adding an `existsBy` method and then a `native mySql update method`. I increased performance 3 times (compared if I have used `findById/getOne + save`). Don't you know accidently, are there any other alternatives ?

Comment: I don't know why you believe that a select statement is issued. I bet this is because your debugger initializes the object by calling `toString()`. `getOne()` should not initialize the entity. Maybe it's your code that causes this.